# Port lastIndexOf AS3 code to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm trying to port an AS3 code to PHP that finds tags (hashtags) at the end of a text block. I'm stuck at the part for `lastIndexOf`. How do I write it in PHP?

AS3:

```
var message = "Lorem #ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur #1tag #2tag #3tag"
while (message.lastIndexOf(" ") == message.lastIndexOf(" #")){
    message = message.slice(0,message.lastIndexOf(" "));
}
```

I tried the code but got this error: `unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)` 
PHP:

```
$message = "Lorem #ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur #1tag #2tag #3tag";
while (strrchr(" ",$message) == strrchr(" #",$message)){
    $message = $message.substr(0,strrchr(" ",$message));
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at regular expressions and PHP's preg_match http://php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 1):

Add `;` symbol at the end of the next line:

```
$message = "Lorem #ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur #1tag #2tag #3tag"
```

And swap arguments in the all `strrchr` functions.

```
strrchr(" ",$message)
strrchr($message, " ")
```

Comment: Just tried it but the echo is empty.`$message = "Lorem #ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur #1tag #2tag #3tag";

    while (strrchr($message," ") == strrchr($message," #")){
    $message = $message.substr(0,strrchr($message," "));
    } echo $message;` The echo should output `#1tag #2tag #3tag`

Answer (score 0):

[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) is the equivalence of lastIndexOf() in AS3.